# How can django sql queries use case insensitive and contains at the same time?

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have two users with username 'AbA' and 'aBa' in the database.
My query word is 'ab'.

I used

`User.objects.filter(username__contains='ab')`

and

`User.objects.filter(username__iexact='ab')`

These two queries get empty result. However, I want to use something like `username__contains__iexact='ab'` that can retrieve both 'AbA' and 'aBa'.

Anyone know how to resolve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Use:

```
User.objects.filter(username__icontains='ab')
```

Answer (score 14):

`icontains` is case-insensitive - http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-icontains